# Do some actions depending on Item content

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I created new project for Windows Store (C#) from template Split App (XAML).
I want do some things when item selected from SplitPage.

In Split App template when I select item from items list (left) application show me full information about item (right). Template uses data binding for this. But I want do some things (add buttons or textboxes, change color and other) at right side depending of item content.
How it possible?

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: I set OnItemClick event of itemListView. But it not fired when I click by item

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is to use data binding as well. You should first extend your item with additional properties based on which you will show your additional controls:

```
private bool _showAdditionalControls = false;
public bool ShowAdditionalControls
{
    get { return this._showAdditionalControls; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this._showAdditionalControls, value); }
}
```

Now you can bind this property to `Visibility` of your controls:

```
<Button Content="Click Me" 
        Visibility="{Binding ShowAdditionalControls, 
                     Converter={StaticResource StaticToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

For this to work you need to add the converter to `Page.Resources` collection:

```
<common:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="StaticToVisibilityConverter" />
```